# How to avoid endpoint suspension in wso2 esb when actual end point is down

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using message store to store the message in case the actual end point is down. My proxy uses vfs transport, i.e it will read the message from the file and deliver to end point. In case the end point is down it will store the message in configured activemq.

My configuration is working fine when i kept single file. While keeping more files(i.e more messages) and end point is down only first few message get stored others are lost.

Even i searched a lot of content most of them suggesting it is due to End point suspension error. I tried to avoid that, but still the same result.

How to solve the issues ???

Answer (score 1):

if backend endpoint fails,defualt endpoint will be suspended for 30000ms. During suspended time, synapse will not try to send further messages to suspended endpoint.But you can turnoff his behavior by specifying 
`<initialDuration>0</initialDuration>` and `<maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>`

following is sample endpoint with suspension time 0

```
<endpoint name="Endpoint">
       <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService">
           <timeout>
               <duration>30000</duration>
               <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
           </timeout>
           <suspendOnFailure>
               <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
               <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
               <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
               <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
           </suspendOnFailure>
           <markForSuspension>
               <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
           </markForSuspension>
       </address>
   </endpoint>
```

Comment: I have tried with your configuration. It process all the files but only kept first few messages from first few files. After that it process the file but unable to keep the message in message store.