# timeout of WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 as a JMS Consumer

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse

I Have a proxy that is described [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/ESB+as+a+JMS+Consumer)

the transport of the proxy is JMS. the proxy gives messages from jms then it sends messages to back-end over http. after back-end answers the proxy sends an answer back to JMS.

All works well.

Sometimes back-end processes a message longer then 30 sec. In this case the proxy can't send a response back.

wso2carbon.log contains

> TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-04-28 09:32:42,250] ERROR
>   {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender} -  Unable to create a
>   JMSMessageSender for:
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo@3b486731
>   {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender}
>   org.apache.activemq.DestinationDoesNotExistException: The destination
>   temp-queue://ID:debcat-ng.hq.cinvest.chel.su-48732-1429525869210-13397:1:1 does not exist.
>   at
>   arg.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion.addDestination(AbstractRegion.java:148)
>     at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.addDestination(RegionBroker.java:277)
>     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addDestination(BrokerFilter.java:145)
>     at org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisoryBroker.addDestination(AdvisoryBroker.java:174)
>     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addDestination(BrokerFilter.java:145)
>     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addDestination(BrokerFilter.java:145)
>     at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addDestination(MutableBrokerFilter.java:151)
>     at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.addProducer(RegionBroker.java:324)
>     at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedRegionBroker.addProducer(ManagedRegionBroker.java:252)
>     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addProducer(BrokerFilter.java:93)
>     at org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisoryBroker.addProducer(AdvisoryBroker.java:162)
>     at org.apache.activemq.broker.CompositeDestinationBroker.addProducer(CompositeDestinationBroker.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addProducer(BrokerFilter.java:93)
>     at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addProducer(MutableBrokerFilter.java:99)
>     at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddProducer(TransportConnection.java:566)
>     at org.apache.activemq.command.ProducerInfo.visit(ProducerInfo.java:105)
>     at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:329)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-04-28
>   09:32:42,253] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} - 
>   
>   Unexpected error sending message back
>   {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for :
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo@3b486731   at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.handleException(AbstractTransportSender.java:226)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:119)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:163)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:268)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportSender.java:148)
>     at
>   ru.chelinvest.wso2esb.transport.XGateSender.sendMessage(XGateSender.java:205)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

the key lines are:

**org.apache.activemq.DestinationDoesNotExistException: The destination
 temp-queue://ID:debcat-ng.hq.cinvest.chel.su-48732-1429525869210-13397:1:1 does not exist.**

**Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}**

**Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for : org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo@3b486731**

why is that happened when time of processing a message exceed 30 sec? how can I expand that timeout?

Comment: I've descovered that the reason of the error is in other side. Actualy I have another ESB that sends messages to JMS. the ESB sends a message. it waits 30 sec. and writes to log next line: `WARN {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender} -  Did not receive a JMS response within 30000 ms to destination : temp-queue://ID:debcat-ng.hq.cinvest.chel.su-48732-1429525869210-16453:1:1 with JMS correlation ID : ID:debcat-ng.hq.cinvest.chel.su-48732-1429525869210-16453:1:1:1:1 {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender}` how can i increase that timeout?

Comment: Does the message that you pass through ESB is the same message with the same corelation ID that is send back?

Comment: @Kacu the question is Why does the JMSSender of ESB wait only 30 sec? How can I tune it?

Comment: Try this with endpoints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343666/how-to-avoid-endpoint-suspension-in-wso2-esb-when-actual-end-point-is-down

Comment: @Kacu . it is about a connecting timeout. I need a timeout for processing. Anyway. I've tried it. It doesn't help me.

Comment: @Kacu. Maybe these is a special property for a message. Obviasly, org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender does not have a special method to set the timeout. I think there is not a solution for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [class JMSSender at github](https://github.com/a13m/wsdl2c/blob/master/src/org/apache/axis2/transport/jms/JMSSender.java). Obviosly, I should define a property JMS_WAIT_REPLY. I've defined it in my endpoint at the sending side. The response timeout for temp-queue is expanded.
Here is my endpoint for sending:

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="xgate">
   <address uri="jms:/....">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
      <timeout>
         <duration>60000</duration>
         <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
      </timeout>
   </address>
   <property name="CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING" value="Windows-1251" scope="axis2"/>
   <property name="CONNECTION_TIMEOUT" value="120000" scope="default"/>
   <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
   <property name="JMS_WAIT_REPLY" value="60000" scope="axis2"/>
   <property name="SO_TIMEOUT" value="120000" scope="default"/>
</endpoint>
```